# YouTube Analytics response 403 for requests for more than one user

Tags: youtube-analytics

This is my client setup

```
$this->_client = new Google_Client();
$this->_client->setClientId( $_config['OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID'] );
$this->_client->setClientSecret( $_config['OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET'] );
$this->_client->setScopes( array( 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly' ) );
$this->_client->setAccessType( 'offline' );
$this->_client->setRedirectUri( filter_var( $_config['OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI'] ),  FILTER_SANITIZE_URL );


$this->_analytics = new YoutubeAnalyticsClient( $this, $this->_client );
```

I make this for each user signed in the system

```
$this->_analytics->setChannelId( $_usr_yt_channel_id );
$this->_analytics->setStartDate( $_period[0] );
$this->_analytics->setEndDate( $_period[1] );
```

I have not getting such response only for first sign in user

```
2014-06-27 12:39:48 Exception: Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DUCoZb0E-9pd6O7BPhd-tU2NA&amp;start-date=2014-06-15&amp;end-date=2014-06-25&amp;metrics=views&amp;dimensions=country&amp;filters=video%3D%3DftqqLcm5U1U&amp;sort=-views&amp;quotaUser=UCoZb0E-9pd6O7BPhd-tU2NA: (403) Forbidden
2014-06-27 12:39:51 Exception: Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DUCoZb0E-9pd6O7BPhd-tU2NA&amp;start-date=2014-06-15&amp;end-date=2014-06-25&amp;metrics=viewerPercentage&amp;dimensions=ageGroup&amp;filters=video%3D%3DftqqLcm5U1U&amp;sort=ageGroup&amp;quotaUser=UCoZb0E-9pd6O7BPhd-tU2NA: (403) Forbidden
```

Removing "quotaUser" doesn't change anything.